# Is it possible to combine flexbox and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

Is there any way to work with CSS3 Flexbox and Bootstrap in the same project?

I mean, if I use CSS Flexbox code like this:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
...
```

Everything goes great until I put the link to Bootstrap CSS file (or CDN). After that everything screw-up.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Instead of implementing flexbox first then adding Bootstrap which, as you noted, can result in conflicting rules, try the reverse:

Use the Bootstrap framework, then use their implementation of flexbox.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Looks like the link that you have shared does not exist anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599396/flexbox-vs-twitter-bootstrap-or-similar-framework
```

Of course, you can use both in a project. A lot of people is doing that. In fact for making equal height columns you can use flexbox in bootstrap. Check the code pen link below for better understanding.

```
http://codepen.io/ShuvoHabib/pen/pyXQNv
```